# BaseExpandableListAdapter getChildView checking boolean condition

Tags: android

I am making a shopping list, and using ExpandableListview to achieve it and it have some group items with children in it, i made a functionality of deleting group and children and in every group there is a last child namely "add item".

Now the problem is in UI, in add item i am hiding the delete button because it doesn't make a sense.

hiding is done by passing a field to arraylist which finally fills my listview, It worked fine by checking it in a condition and assigning state accordingly but when i scroll the hidden delete button become visible and vice-versa.

i have tried lots of fixes but no luck, like using Viewholder implementation.

please somebody help me, i really need a quick solution.

if any other information is needed please ask me, and please give me the answer.

**Thanks**

EDIT: Sorry but i can't share some part of the code , rest is this

```
public class MyListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

private Context context;
private ArrayList<HeaderInfo> deptList;
ShoppingListFragment ShoppingListFrag;
ArrayList<HashMap<View, Boolean>> alValues;

DatabaseHelper db;

public MyListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HeaderInfo> deptList,
        ShoppingListFragment ownerFragment) {
    this.context = context;
    this.deptList = deptList;
    db = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    this.ShoppingListFrag = ownerFragment;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    ArrayList<DetailInfo> productList = deptList.get(groupPosition)
            .getProductList();
    return productList.get(childPosition);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    // View vi = view;
    ViewHolderChild holder = null;
    DetailInfo detailInfo = (DetailInfo) getChild(groupPosition,
            childPosition);

    Boolean bFlag = ((DetailInfo) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition))
            .getLastItem();

    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.child_row, null);
        holder = new ViewHolderChild();

        holder.childItem = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.childItem);
        holder.tvRemover = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_removeItem);


        view.setTag(holder);
        view.setTag(R.id.childItem, detailInfo.getLastItem());
        view.setTag(R.id.heading, detailInfo.getTagId());


    } else {

        holder = (ViewHolderChild) view.getTag();

        view.getTag(R.id.childItem);
        view.getTag(R.id.heading);

    }

    holder.childItem.setText(detailInfo.getName().trim());

    Log.e("MyListAdapter, GetChildView",
            "Group Pos: "
                    + groupPosition
                    + ", Child Pos: "
                    + childPosition
                    + ", Last Item Pos: "
                    + ((DetailInfo) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition))
                            .getLastItem() + ", bflag: " + bFlag
                    + ", view: " + view);


    if (detailInfo.getLastItem()) {
        holder.tvRemover.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }


    view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            // Checking if it is last item
            if (Boolean.parseBoolean(v.getTag(R.id.childItem).toString())) {
                //adding child to the corresponding group
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, " item", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });

    holder.tvRemover.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //Removing child from the group
        }
    });

    return view;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {

    ArrayList<DetailInfo> productList = deptList.get(groupPosition)
            .getProductList();
    return productList.size();

}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return deptList.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return deptList.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isLastChild, View view,
        ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    HeaderInfo headerInfo = (HeaderInfo) getGroup(groupPosition);
    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inf.inflate(R.layout.group_heading, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.heading = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.heading);
        holder.imgdelete = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img_delete);
        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }
    LibFunctions.setTypeFace(context, holder.heading,
            "AvantGardeMedium.OTF");
    holder.heading.setText(headerInfo.getName().trim());

    holder.imgdelete.setTag(headerInfo);
    Log.e("MyListActivity", "groupPosition: " + groupPosition);

    holder.imgdelete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //Deleting group here

        }
    });

    return view;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView heading;
    ImageView imgdelete;

}

static class ViewHolderChild {
    TextView tvRemover, childItem;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}
```

}

**Please help**

Comment: Show some code you implemented until now

Comment: added some code @Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with existing code, Just changed the condition check, it was a silly mistake.

But i am still a little bit confused why is the view at other position was resembled as the view which was being checked as visible or not.

anyways here is the change in code i've implemented :

```
final Boolean bFlag = ((DetailInfo) getChild(groupPosition,
                    childPosition)).getLastItem();
.
.
.

if (bFlag) {
            holder.tvRemover.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            holder.tvRemover.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
```

So, the mistake was after checking the condition the view was gone but it was not reverting it back to visible properly.

**thanks everyone.**

Answer (score 0):

Since you have two different Viewtypes, you shouldn't use only one view and modify it.

Instead you should use two different views and implement `getViewTypeCount()` and `getItemViewType(int position)` to display the corresponding view.

[**This Thread**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777272/android-listview-with-different-layout-for-each-row) should help you